# Cannot generate required string with reduce in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback

I have this error and can not solve this. I tried looking for asked questions and none answers my problem.I tried working with the code, it looks simple but yet confusing as I'm just learning this.
I want output as `Nepal, China and the United States`

I have this code:

```
import { countries } from "./data.js";
console.log(countries.reduce((x='',country)=>{
   if(!x.includes('and')){ 
/*array does not contain and & we need    
terminate if statement for the last value of x.*/
    x += (country +", ")
   }else{
    x +=(' and the ' + country)
   }
   return x;
}))
```

Countries is an array
 ['Nepal','China','United States']

and the output that I am getting is: `NepalChina, United States, `. 
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: If the string doesn't contain "and" you add a comma. You never actually add "and" in this way, though, since in order to add it it musts exist.

Comment: what does `countries` actually contain?

Comment: @VLAZ got that, I did noticed that I have some wrong conditions set there but can you help me get that desired output?

Comment: @Portal `'Nepal',
    'China',
    'United States'`

Comment: so none of them contain `and`

Comment: @Portal yes, now we need to terminate the if statement for last item of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let countries = ['Nepal','China','United States'];
console.log(countries.reduce((x, country, index, countries) => {
  if(index === countries.length - 1)
    return x += ', and ' + country;
  else
    return x += ', ' + country;
}));
```

We need to remove the check for `and` since that isn't present in the initial array. We also need to know when we are on the last iteration here which I've done above by checking `if(index === countries.length - 1)`

Comment: Thnx you so much :)